# Will SO (eventually) invalidate some copyrights and patents?

Tags: discussion, legal, copyright, licensing, intellectual-property

This is an open-discussion and forward-looking question. It is not designed to incite trolling :)

There are a number of questions here that [detail the licensing of and ownership of code posted on SO.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/search?q=Copyright)

It seems that answers here will cover code that will become the basis of other's copyrighted or otherwise proprietary work. Might the ***publication date of code here*** eventually be effective in overturning software copyrights?  Might it eventually be shown as prior art against patent filings?

Comment: I don't see how this can become a productive discussion, as all we can offer is our collective speculation. Either way, the risk of stuff like this is why nobody sane should copy/paste code from SO answers into their products. It's no different from publication anywhere else, though.

Comment: Might not the same question be asked about code posted on any site on the Internet (or published in books, journals, ...)?

Comment: The question is designed to create discussion about **what SO could become, as time goes by**.  Everything evolves as the world changes around its original, intended, purpose.  Understanding how people will-or-will-not use the site seems rather important to chaping and growing this community

Comment: It's not really clear what kind of discussion you're after, NewAlexandria. To emphasize my earlier point, the effect on a given patent by prior art is the same, no matter where that art is found, and the copyright applied to that art makes little to no difference. They're orthogonal concepts. Maybe you could provide an example of the kind of discussion or proposal that you'd like to see here.

Comment: (not an IP lawyer, but played one for my last project, so I'm *pretty* confident in the assertions I've made above)

Comment: SO could be a more semantically mine-able source, and thus promote a code 'grammar' that could be used to easier search for code that invalidates a copyright or patent

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, this is theoretically possible.

> [image: I am not often shocked. Right now I am totally flabbergasted.]

That'll be the expression of the person it happens to. If it ever happens, and if anyone can ever prove anything, and if anyone really cares about 3 lines of code, and if everyone lives in a jurisdiction suitable for suing, and if the right people can even be found, and if the person who originally licensed it by posting it on Stack Overflow really cares, and if ...

Comment: [Or maybe this](http://cdn2.joshuakennon.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/01/Grumpy-Cat-Narcissism-Test.jpeg)

Comment: Your name changes are getting really disconcerting Andrew/@TheFestivusUnicorn :-). That has the look of your own cat? Not that I know what you cat looks like, of course, ahem, but the photo might not be one stolen off the interwebz.

Comment: Yeah; I 'realized' that I was sort of abusing the name changes, so I've stopped :)

Comment: Oh, and just because I stole it off the Internet doesn't mean it couldn't be my cat!

Comment: There can only be one unicorn moderator.

Comment: Unicorn fight! Could Boltclock and The Festivus Unicorn (I can't believe I wrote that) have a mod-off @TheGrinch. We can get a Lizard and Chris' dog involved as well!

Comment: I'm in! Festivus FTW!